3rd party keyboard not recognized at startup
What must I do to enable recognition of my logi keyboard at startup.
macOS fails to recognize logi "MX MCHNCL M" * keyboard at startup.
I must enter login credentials via Mac Magic Keyboard.
After startup input from the logi keyboard is accepted.
The logi keyboard is recognized by bluetooth.
System Settings/keyboard doesn't appear to have the ability to recognize a default keyboard.

Logitech MX Mechanical Keyboard?


Do you use FileVault?  Many third-party keyboards are not recognized over Bluetooth before the FileVault login.
